# Is finding dead-end nodes in NL?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs

Given a directed graph $G$ and two nodes $s,t$, decide whether there is some node $s'$ such that $s'$ is reachable from $s$ while $t$ is *not* reachable from $s'$.

I am wondering whether this problem is in [NL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NL_%28complexity%29).

Comment: The problem is even NL-complete under logspace reduction. Check the Wikipedia page on st-connectivity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is in NL.  Here is the outline of a possible proof:

- If you already fix *s*′, you can check whether *s*′ satisfies your condition or not in NL.  Reachability is easy, non-reachability is by the [Immerman–Szelepcsényi theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immerman%E2%80%93Szelepcs%C3%A9nyi_theorem), and taking the AND of two conditions is easy.
- Because there are only polynomially many possibilities for *s*′, you can test these possibilities one by one until you find the right *s*′ or find out that no such *s*′ exists.  Alternatively, you can guess *s*′ by using nondeterminism.